# how to avoid bypass SQL server injection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-injection

I have the following C# code :

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from employ where name = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and Snumber =  
'" + textBox2.Text + "'", cn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not null");
            dt.Clear();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("is null");

        }
```

QUESTION: How to avoid bypass injection

I'm using SQL Server 2008 (9.0 RTM)

Thanks in advance

Comment: the (dt) is datatable

Comment: SQL Server **2008** is SQL Server **v10.0** (v9.0 = SQL Server 2005) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid SQL injection by using [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM employ WHERE name = @name AND Snumber = @number";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",  textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number",  textBox2.Text);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters:

```
...Where name=@name
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
```

Or use stored procedure

eg:

SQL:

```
CREATE PROC sp_Employ_GetByName
   @name varchar(50)
as
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM EMPLOY
    WHERE NAME=@name
        AND .....
END
```

C#:

```
//connect....
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Employ_GetByName", ...your connection...);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@....", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = ...;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
//.......
```